# Motivation for considering the upper numbering of ramification groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension. We denote by $G_s$ its $s$-th ramification group. Define the Herbrand function $$\eta_{L/K}:[-1,\infty) \to [-1, \infty), \ \eta_{L/K}(s) = \int_0^s \frac{1}{(G_0:G_x)} \ dx.$$ Let $\psi_{L/K} : [-1, \infty) \to [-1, \infty)$ be its inverse. Then, introducing the *upper numbering* $G^t = G_{\psi(t)}$ has many uses.

This is great but what is the motivation to actually consider this numbering? I'll admit that my intuition on ramification groups is still quite weak but for me it seems a bit out of the blue. Is it just because Herbrand's Theorem $G_s(L/K)H/H = G_{\eta_{L/L'}(s)}(L'/K)$ for an intermediate field $L'$ appears more natural, so one would try considering a different numbering? Is there a different motivation?

Comment: In Serre's Local Fields he gives a nice explanation relating the two starting on the bottom of page 75 and going to the next page (Remark 3). The lower numbering has many nice properties, and after one finds that it is compatible with subgroups but not quotients, so it is very natural to look for another numbering that does work with quotients.

Comment: Also Lubin has a nice article "Elementary analytic methods in higher ramification theory" which (if I understand it) could address your question a little.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that lower ramification groups behave well when taking subgroups, while upper ramification groups behave well when taking quotients. As a result, the upper numbering can be defined for infinite extensions. I think this is the key motivation for defining them.

Indeed, if $L/K$ is an infinite extension, we can define
$$\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)^u = \varprojlim_{M/K\ \mathrm{finite}, M\subset L}\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)^u.$$

This definition makes sense by Herbrand's theorem, which tells us that we get a projective system to take the limit of.

In this way, the upper ramification groups are far more natural than the lower ramification groups.

The lower ramification groups have the advantage that they are easier to define and are sufficient for finite extensions. They also behave well with respect to subgroups: if $L/M/K$ is a sequence of Galois extensions, then
$$\mathrm{Gal}(L/M)_i = \mathrm{Gal}(L/M)\cap \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)_i.$$

Comment: Thank you, that helped! This is not quite what I am looking for, though. When I wrote that 
the "upper numbering have many uses" I was indeed thinking of things like the definition of ramification groups for infinite extensions. My question was that e.g. if I was developing the theory of ramification groups and started introducing the lower numbering, why would I ever think about introducing the higher numbering without having seen it before?

Comment: The (I think sole) motivation is to find a system of ramification groups that can be used in applications where we want to consider quotients of Galois groups rather than subgroups of Galois groups.